# CMD - Removing text from an input

Tags: cmd, set

So what I basically want to do is something like the command ping:

First you enter ping and then some ip EX: 192.168.1.1 so the command looks like `ping 192.168.1.1`.
If I type something like this: `pingip 192.168.1.1` into my program how do I then execute a ping command pinging only the IP .. So without the "pingip" text there..
So how do I REMOVE the "pingip" part from there ?

```
@echo off
title Console
color a

:start
cls
echo.
set /p input="> "

I enter Pingip (theip) !

How do I then  ping %input%  WITHOUT THE PINGIP part (Only the IP).
```

Comment: You are asking how to validate user input. This is difficult in a batch file. PowerShell is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `pingip` string from the variable `input`.

```
SET "ADDR=%input:pingip=%"
ping %ADDR%
```

Comment: Doesn't work .. Can you be more specific with the command please

Comment: In what way does it "Doesn't work .."? What is the value of the `input` variable before these commands?